# Node.JS/Express - how to avoid multiple database queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a basic express app and im getting started with db queries and i want to know how to avoid multiple db queries because i dont think its efficient the way i do it :

```
app.get('/:word', function(req,res){

    db.create({'name': word});

    console.log('the word is ' + word);
});
```

What i want to do is  :

1. get the word from the url
2. check if it exists in the datbaase (or previously requested because if it was then it was probably added already through this basic code)
3. if it doesn't exist then add it and then proceed to console.log

I want to add each word to my database once only and not run the db query again and again.

Here's what im thinking :

Not so efficient way
query to check if it exists before inserting one

Good way but i dont know how to start here
Cache the word being queried and maintain cache to prevent db queries

**More info edit**

I'm using mongodb via mongoose
the 'word' key is already unique so i know its not creating duplicate values

i dont want to run ANY db queries if that value or that url has already been hit once

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: Is this just example code? Or is this your actual implementation. I'd like to discourage you from creating entries through the use of GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check if the word already exists is to query the database before inserting. There are libraries (and also database) that implements the `findOrCreate` method, but this is always just an abstraction. Behind the scenes, the database will search for an existing value before writing.

If your database is huge and queryng is not suitable, **you could use a cashing system** (like Redis). But this definitely depends on your logic and your data size.

Probably you can just optimize the process just **adding and index to the column you want be unique** (I guess it's `name`?).

You could also **define the column `name` as unique**. When inserting, the database will throw you an error if the document already exists. But keep in mind again that, behind the scenes, the database is queryng for an existing same value before inserting. The advantage to have an "unique" column is that the index for this column is automatically created and also from your app logic (node js) you can just call the insert method and add a little bit error handling logic.

Comment: ive already done the unique index and currently im trying to avoid ANY db queries if that word or the url address has been hit before (some kind of wierd caching)

Comment: so, redis is the way.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will create any collections you use in your app if they do not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Insert Unique Value :**

Create [Unique Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) to your key, So that the value will be added only once. If you try to add again it will throws an error to you.

To create Unique Index,

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

**Caching :**

For caching, Store your data on cache system(Like: [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache), [redis](https://redis.io/)) on first time data will be query from MongoDB and then for subsequent need of data you can use cache system.

Answer (score 0):

In mongo db you can use findOneAndUpdate with optional flag upsert: true [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior)

To ensure that every word appears only once you should also set unique index on that field. However rememer that unique index is case sensitive so Cat and cat are different words.